# Put all events from fullcalendar in a global variable

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I need to put the events of my fullcalendar in a global variable.

This my code :

```
var allevents =new Array();
    $(document).ready(function () {

     $('#calendarDay').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
           allevents = $('#calendarDay').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
     });

> allevents.lengh = 1 ;
```

and when I declare the variable in function like this :

```
function eventcalender() {

    allevents = $('#calendarDay').fullCalendar('clientEvents');

}
```

> allevents.length= 5 ;

and I get all my events with their details.

I need to have the events of my calendar in a global variable. Is there a mistake or another way to fix this?

Comment: not really answers but: your code has a typo (I think) in `allevents.lengh = 1` - missing the letter T in length, and sometimes you spell calendar correctly with an A at the end (calendAr, which is correct) other times with an E (calendEr is incorrect). These inconsistencies may be causing issues.

Comment: Im sorry for all those typo, the code is correct. when i use allevents in $(document).ready(function ()...{}); I get only one object: [object Object]{0: HTMLDivElement {...}, context: Document {...}, jquery: "1.11.1", length: 1, selector: "#calendarDay"}